# How this (migrated) question is related to the site?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I just came across a question <sup>[1]</sup> that was [migrated here from superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1331515/in-moodle-3-1-videos-and-files-are-not-opeing-in-embed-format?noredirect=1).

It seems that this question is more about an upgrade of Moodle that encountered problems, rather than a problem with a web application.

I really don't see how it belongs here, what am I missing here?

---

<sup><sup>[1]</sup> [In moodle 3.1 videos and files are not opeing in embed format](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/118378/in-moodle-3-1-videos-and-files-are-not-opeing-in-embed-format)</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are occasionally misunderstandings in terms of scope.

There may have been a time in the distant past in which such questions would be on-topic here, and many people on SE still haven't caught up with our "new" focus (as a related example, many people still think we accept things like web app requests, which we haven't entertained for years now).

The specific situation has been taken care of and the migration was rejected.  Thanks for pointing it out.