# Did someone just decides to intentionally down vote my posts?

Tags: support, down-votes, serial-voting

I noticed that in the last few hours (or half a day), 4 of my posts were down voted (3 regular, 1 meta).

It made me wonder if it was done on purpose.
Not that I don't accept being down voted, it means I should check again the question to be sure it's good - but right now it just seems weird.

From my experience, it's odd to get so many (relatively) down votes in such a short period, and without a single comment explaining it. Moreover, two of the questions are around 2 month old, and got positive feedback until that moment, and so again - no explanation about the reason.

The relevant posts: [1](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/116656/disable-facebook-up-next-popup-and-next-video-play), [2](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/116926/is-it-possible-to-delete-all-facebook-app-posts-without-removing-the-app), [3](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/118431/how-heroku-signup-process-details-affect-usage), [4](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4559/how-this-migrated-question-is-related-to-the-site).

So is it just coincidence or it was done on purpose?

---

Screenshot from `summary --> Reputation`:

[image]

Comment: If you haven't already seen this: [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/21960)

Comment: I've seen something similar, wasn't sure if that's the case or it's just a coincidence (and how to know that). Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without commenting any further on the specifics, I can tell you that we're aware of this and are taking action.

Comment: If it's any consolation, I apparently cheesed somebody off a couple of weeks ago and they went on a downvote spree against me, not just here but on [su] and [meta.se]. The vote reversal worked for each instance, so I shrugged it off.

Comment: Oh! I haven't known it's such a common thing. But I learned that the system knows  how to take care of it, which is really cool

Comment: @jonsca, can you please check that again? All my latest questions (which weren't a lot since I wasn't very active in the past year) got downoted pretty fast, which led to their deletion. And I'm pretty sure not all of them are so bad.

Comment: It's less about the few points, and more about the fact that I can't ask anything anymore, since it's just getting downvoted and then unnoticed

Comment: @arieljannai I undeleted your latest two questions that were deleted.  I don't see you as blocked by the system, so you should be all set.

Comment: @jonsca I guess if you did it it means there was something around it, so thanks for the kind help!